# Database not being cleared when using Capybara and RSPEC

Tags: rspec, capybara, factory-bot

I've been having some problems with my database lately.  At first I thought it was a factorygirl problem, but then I realized that factorygirl was (probably) not actually using the data that wasn't being cleared.

Anyway, I first use factorygirl to create a new user.  I then log in as the user and navigate to the page where I can create a new "foo" with data fields "foo_name" and "bar".  Next, I fill_in "". :with => "" the fields and click_button "Save" to create the new "foo" object.  After that I check the index of the new object and it should be 1, but each time I run the test, the number goes up by 4. (it's on 72 right now)

Additionally, I find that I need to delete the old user at the beginning of the test or factorygirl will complain that the user has already been created.

I was almost certain that RSPEC was supposed to handle the deletion of the test database for me, am I wrong?  And if so, would anyone have some good advice about a "good" way to clear the database?  I've been looking around for several days already and it's been a real bummer so far.

Thank you very much.

Edit (some example code requested):

```
...
  context "can create a new FooBar" do
    before {
      find_link('New Foo Bar').click
    }
    it 'has current_path "/foo_bar/new"' do
      current_path.should == '/foo_bar/new'
    end
    context "when the correct information is given" do
      before {
        fill_in 'Name', :with => 'TestFooBar'
        fill_in 'Description', :with => 'A test foo bar'
        click_button 'Save'
      }
      it 'has current_path "/foo_bars"' do
        current_path.should == '/foo_bars'
      end
...
```

After this, I check how many foo_bars there are

Comment: Can you post some code examples that you can't seem to get working?

Comment: Edited OP.

Apologies, I don't know if that's helpful enough though.  Also, does the fact that the user, which is a grandparent-owner of foo_bar, was created by factorygirl affect the scope of foo_bar?  I've seen on other posts that rspec doesn't clear factorygirl things.

Comment: If you are using Capybara with Selenium, you can't use transactional fixtures, as explained here: http://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/#using-capybara-with-testunit

That means you need to clear out the test database yourself, or use Database Cleaner or a similar gem. 

RSpec is not at fault here.

Comment: Aright, that's good to know.  Thank you very much!
How can I give you credit for that answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who needs this in the future, this problem has been solved.
Like zetetic said, I can't use Capybara with transactional fixtures.

To fix the problem, I used Database Cleaner.

gem install database_cleaner

```
Gemfile:
group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

bundle install

spec/spec_helper.rb:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
...
module ::RSpec::Code
  class ExampleGroup
    include Capybara::DSL
    include Capybara::RSpecMatchers
  end
end
```

foo_bar file:

```
before(:all) {
  ...
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
}
after(:all) {
  ...
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
  Capybara.reset_sessions!
  Capybara.use_default_driver
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your spec should not rely on the assumption that the first row will be created with ID==1.

As for cleaning out the test database, normally RSpec takes care of this by running each spec in a transaction, and rolling back changes when the example is complete. This will happen if your configuration has the line:

`config.use_transactional_fixtures = true`

If you need to set this to false, you can use a tool like [Database Cleaner](http://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) to clear out the database after each example.

Comment: In my spec_helper.rb file, I have the
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
line.  It's not that I expect the the row to have ID==1, it's just that I'm probably using space that I don't need to be using if the count is not going back down.

I found that if I use rake db:test:prepare, the database is cleared and the count is back to normal.  I also tried including this in my code with Rake::Task['db:test:prepare'].invoke, but it gave me an error
Don't know how to build task